# I have forced my IP address to go to a different page with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have made a code in the htaccess below:

```
# TO MAKE A DIFFERENT PAGE FOR A SPECIFIED IP-ADRES
    RewriteEngine On
    #DENY THIS SPECIFIED IP-ADRES OR REDIRECT IT TO ANOTHER PAGE (=something like iframe)
        #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$ 
        #RewriteRule index\.html$ index2\.html [L]
```

Let's just say my IP address is 1.2.3.4. How can I delete this code and that I go back to the normal `index.html` instead of being redirect to `index2.html`?

Comment: Remove the code from htaccess?

Comment: Yes I already tried but than I still go the index2.html file

Comment: Sounds like the redirect is cached in either server or client then.

Comment: How can I delete the cache of my website, I'm using coda 1